# Why does inheriting from GroovyTestCase cause Spring errors in Grails 2.2?

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, integration-testing

The integration test classes generated for me by Grails when I created my domain classes do not extend the class GroovyTestCase. However, I have seen it recommended by many authors ([here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-testing-for-expected.html) is an example in order to use the `shouldFail` method, which indeed seems to work).

However, extending my test class from GroovyTestCase has resulted in the following error message when I run `test-app` in the interactive Grails console:

```
Spring Loaded: Cannot reload new version of foo.barTests
Reason: Supertype changed from java/lang/Object to groovy/util/GroovyTestCase
```

Is this something I should be concerned about? I have searched online and cannot find other people complaining about this error, so it might be something new with Grails 2.2. Please advise.

---

I am running my tests in the grails interactive console (what you get when you run `grails` without arguments). I've left my tests inheriting from Object for a while, but when I run `test-app` I still  occasionally get those messages output to the HTML test report (of the "changed from GroovyTestCase to Object" variety).

Comment: Did you tried `grails clean` before another `grails test-app` ? Does it produce the same error ?

Comment: For information, your link is outdated (it was about grails 1.3.x)

Comment: Strangely enough, when I undo the extension, grails complains about the inverse again (`changed from groovy/util/GroovyTestCase to java/lang/Object`), and it does so even when I do a `grails clean` first.

Comment: Are you running these tests inside of GGTS or on command line?  If GGTS, then what version?

Comment: I'm using the grails interactive console. Please see updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am quite sure it's a Grails bug related to

1. AST Transformation annotations
2. spring-loaded module

As I've encountered this strange behaviour as well.

The steps that caused this problem seem to be that a Groovy class is compiled once without transformation, so that it's a subclass of `java.lang.Object`.

When the AST transformaton kicks it, the class is recompiled again. This time, it becomes a subclass of another class. Then Spring-loaded fails to re-load them into the memory (as JVM does not allow the same class to redefine its super class).

Comment: If this is indeed a bug in Grails, do you think it could have a negative effect in a production environment? (I'm afraid my own knowledge of spring-loaded is very limited.) Should I revert to an earlier version of Grails, perhaps, to be safe?

Comment: @Stephan Don't worry, it's safe for production. I've got a 2.2 app running already in the cloud.

Spring-loaded works only in the `dev` environment.